# What is the policy on OP deleting the posted question?

Tags: discussion

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578202/pig-filter-not-working-correctly) on Stack Overflow that I was following because I was trying to troubleshoot the issue and was interested to know the answer.

The question seemed perfectly fine to me (and there were no downvotes either), and there were a few others along with me trying to figure out the problem. However, all of a sudden the OP decides to remove the question.

Now I am deprived of the opportunity to find out the answer, and I cannot recreate the problem and try to solve it myself.

So I'm just wondering if there is/should be any policy on OPs deleting their posted questions in such circumstances.

Comment: If there are no upvoted answers, that is fair game. If there are, he can't delete the question.

Comment: There are many good reasons for an OP to delete a question: s/he made a silly mistake, or recognized that some other factor caused the problem, or figured out the answer, or found the answer elsewhere and realized that the question was trivial.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Those are good reasons to answer your own question, not reasons to delete the question.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure that is always the case. Silly mistakes can be typos: those questions aren't helpful to the masses. Questions with answers elsewhere on the site are dupes. Questions with answers that end up being related to a non-code related are off-topic (for SO).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins In such a case you can still answer, or comment with the solution, and in most of those cases it probably would be appropriate to close the question.  I don't see a compelling reason to delete it though.  It may get deleted automatically after a little while if others don't find it useful, which should be fine.

Comment: @Servy I'll defer to your knowledge, but I'm not sure I understand. If the user recognizes it as a bad question and has no intention of improving it, what is the benefit of leaving it around? (Except in the cases of chronic deleters who get autobanned after a while.)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Just because you think nobody will find it useful doesn't always mean you can't be surprised.  Rather than deleting it because it might not be useful, why not just leave it around for a few days and actually *find out*.  The auto-delete system means that the clutter won't stay around forever if it's found to not have value, so it's not like you're burdened with checking back on it.

Comment: @Servy Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policy on a user deleting posts is that users are able to delete their own contributions.  In the case of answers it means they can delete them whenever they want.  In the case of questions it means they can be deleted so long as there aren't valuable answers that would be deleted along with it (where "valuable" is defined as a score of 1 or more).

If it's noticed that a user is deleting a significant percentage of their content, and a mod feels that they are simply vandalizing their own valuable contributions out of spite, rather than because it really doesn't belong on the site any more, they *may* decide to disassociate the post(s) from the user and un-delete them (a user *always* has the right to have a post disassociated from them).  This is fairly rare though; it's reserved for cases of clear malicious deletions.

Comment: How about defining "valuable" as "more than 3 lines" or so? I just spent 10 minutes writing a fairly comprehensive answer to what I thought was a reasonable question, only for the OP to delete the whole question. I'm not amused.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout If you really feel that the information is not currently accessible anywhere on the web and would be a useful resource to others then you can ask a similar question yourself and provide your answer for others.  You don't need this person's question to have that information out there.  That said, keep in mind writing self-answered questions isn't easy for many people, you need to ensure the question is a high quality question when standing alone, rather than just being some placeholder for your answer.  The question should be clear, complete, adequately scoped, etc. on its own.